# Exit from manual in VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I used man in VS Code terminal on Mac and now I want to exit manual.

Control + C (two times), Control + D (two times), Command + . didn't work. I can't write "exit" neither.
Using bash instead of zsh didn't help too. I can't exit manual in Mac terminal app too.